# Get previous value of an entity

Tags: entity-framework-4

I need to get previous value of an entity.

My requirement is like; I have some input fields in an edit page.

1 User can enter some values there and press **save** button at this time the user should be able to save it.

2 User can enter some values there and press **Cancel** button at this time the page should be reloaded with whatever values were there before the user start editing the page.

My question is that can entity frame work, help us in getting previous value of an object?
Is self tracking  is something related to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would want to do is:

```
myContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, myObject);
```

This will ask the context to reload the entity removing any changes to the object and replacing the property values from the data store.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned "page" so I guess you are talking about web application. In such case you should simply load entity from the database again because pushing Cancel button will make a new request to your web application. You should use a new context per request so you don't have any previous data or entity to reload - you will run a new query and get last data persisted to database.